# python request iugu retorna status 400

Tags: json, python, dicionário, flask

Estou testando a api do [iugu.com](http://iugu.com)  para gerar pagamentos de boletos e estou com problemas no retorno do json porque não há erro em items do dictionary que é enviada para a API (em php seria um array)

o código é o seguinte:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    dados = {
        'method':'bank_slip',
        'email':'cliente@exemplo.com',
        'items[]':[
            {'description':'Item Um', 'quantity':1, 'price_cents': 100000},
            {'description':'Item Dois', 'quantity':1, 'price_cents': 200000}
        ]
    } 

url = 'https://api.iugu.com/v1/charge' 
user = '002f38a6d40b0275fc08aaac503a775b'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, ''), headers = headers, params = json.dumps(dados))

return jsonify(
    resposta = [
        r.json(),
        {
            'status': r.status_code,
            'cabecalho': r.headers['Content-Type'],
            'params': dados,
            'text': r.content,
            'url': r.url
        }
    ])

app.debug = True
app.use_reloader=True
app.run()
```

A resposta:

```
{
  "resposta": [
    {
      "errors": "token n\u00e3o \u00e9 v\u00e1lido"
    }, 
    {
      "cabecalho": "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      "params": {
        "email": "cliente@exemplo.com", 
        "items[]": [
          {
            "description": "Item Um", 
            "price_cents": 100000, 
            "quantity": 1
          }, 
          {
            "description": "Item Dois", 
            "price_cents": 200000, 
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ], 
        "method": "bank_slip"
      }, 
      "status": 400, 
      "text": "{\"errors\":\"token n\\u00e3o \\u00e9 v\\u00e1lido\"}", 
      "url": "https://api.iugu.com/v1/charge?%7B%22email%22:%20%22cliente@exemplo.com%22,%20%22items[]%22:%20[%7B%22price_cents%22:%20100000,%20%22description%22:%20%22Item%20Um%22,%20%22quantity%22:%201%7D,%20%7B%22price_cents%22:%20200000,%20%22description%22:%20%22Item%20Dois%22,%20%22quantity%22:%201%7D],%20%22method%22:%20%22bank_slip%22,%20%22format%22:%20%22json%22%7D"
    }
  ]
}
```

Se eu tento usar como no exemplo do site que se parece com isso:

```
'items[][description]':'Item Um', 
'items[][quantity]':'1', 
'items[][price_cents]':'100000',
```

a resposta retorna de forma correta, mas não é possível adicionar mais de um item porque ele só considera a segunda inserção. Há uma outra maneira de enviar dados ou eu estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Acho que isso pode ser uma mão na roda pra você https://github.com/iugu/iugu-python

Answer (score 1):

**Questão resolvida**

Recebi uma dica do próprio pessoal da **[iugu.com](http://iugu.com)** para verificar os dados que são enviados via curl, é o **[postcatcher.in](http://postcatcher.in)**. Lá foi possível criar uma sessão e direcionar a url da minha aplicação para a url que fica no brownser depois de start nesse site. Com isso é possível acompanhar em tempo real, na aba body, se os dados foram enviados ou não entre outras observações de cabeçarios entre outras informações (achei muito legal)

Com esse site vi que não era enviado nem items nem nada que queria que fosse e isso me ajudou a ver que o a linha do requests estava errada.

Em vez de usar **params** o certo era usar **data**.

Deu tudo certo.